# How to hide the row header in the first row when no row is selected in a Silverlight DataGrid?

Tags: silverlight

I have a datagrid which shows all the headers of the rows. I have noticed that after the datagrid is populated with some data, even there is no row selected (i.e. SelectedIndex = -1), the little blue rectangle row header still shows in the first row alnog with the first cell highlighted with a blue border... I have successfully got rid of the border surrounding the first cell by modifying the styles of the datagrid, but I just can't get rid of the blue rectangle row header!

Can someone please help me? Thanks a lot!!

Cheers,
Xin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw this question I asked ages ago... quite silly one so I will answer it for myself, lol...

I could either make the RowHeader hidden or, modify the style of DataGridRowHeaderStyle, in the style template, by simply removing CurrentRowGlyph and EditingRowGlyph. :)